# Is it possible to make a spotify playlist available offline using the spotify web api?

Tags: spotify

I had a look to https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/, but didn't find an action to do it. Is it possible to achive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible using the Web API.